# Equine musicians?

Tags: language, wordplay

What is interesting about the following sentence?

> "Furiously, in back of shut portals, one in four silvery equids is only hiding many extra tidings of meadows, somewhat more craftily than normal," extremely fat musicians cried enthusiastically.

<sub>This is not a "guess what I'm thinking" puzzle. The answer will be obvious once you find it.</sub>

Comment: it's less awkward English than some of the posted questions here.   :)

Comment: so to answer my own queried form answer from a previous query. Rand is feeling crazy.

Comment: Seems similar to your French killer. What language is it today :D?

Comment: There is no letter "p" and no "z" in the whole phrase!

Comment: There is a "p" in portals. I think you mean "j" and "z"... Maybe the answer is "Jay Z" ;p

Comment: Oh right, i meant j. Jay Z? Nah, Joe Z.!

Comment: Useless facts! 29 words made of 159 alphabet characters. 55 syllables. 100 consonants and 59 vowels (93 and 66 if Y is a vowel). The first letter of each word spells FIBOSPOIFSEIOHMETOMSMCTNEFMCE. The last letters spell YNKFTSENRYSSYGYASFSTEYNLYTSDY. The little dot over the lowercase i & j is called a tittle. The first ever air-to-ground radio message was, "Roy, come and get this goddamn cat."

Comment: Well the fat musicians must be rather horrible at music if they are crying nonsense.

Comment: @leoll2 Not everything revolves around me. :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Synonyms form a sentence that is

> in alphabetical order

I'm not sure this is quite right, but here's what I think:

> "Angrily, behind closed doors, every fourth gray horse is just keeping lots more news of pastures quiet rather sneakier than usual," very wide xylophonists yelled zealously.

Comment: Might be worth trying to look up song lyrics that would fit this.

Comment: @Spacemonkey, Radio Head - "Roy, come and get this goddamn cat." (Their unreleased single inspired by science and Engineer Toast!)

Comment: Bravo! I had "slylier", "weighty", "yelped", and "zestfully", but doesn't matter - yours works just as well. Congratulations :-)

Comment: The trickiest part was realizing that "keeping quiet" was the correct synonym for "hiding", because the two words straddle the phrase in between them rather than being grouped together. Really fun puzzle, though, I love puzzles that have more to solve once you figure out the "trick"!

Comment: Xylophonists is not a synonym for musicians :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm ignoring some clues here, but here's my guess

> It's a violin

There's my reasoning

> Four fat cat musicians - The strings of a violin are traditionally made from the gut of some kind of animal. Often falsely thought to be cat gut. 
>  The bow string for classical stringed instruments is typically made from horse hair (usually tail), so that could be the whole 'equid' statement.

Comment: But the question wasn't a riddle!

Comment: Then I'm incorrect. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

> You used every different type of word in the English language.

Or that;

> Every type of grammatically correct ... uhm.. grammar thingy .. was used.

For every

> Noun there is a adverb and adjective describing it.

Comment: What??? This isn't very precise (and is way off, actually). From the OP: "The answer will be obvious once you find it."

Comment: Grasping at straws.. I may need another cup of coffee