# Why Alexa Shouldn't Teach Non-Native English Speakers About Idioms

Tags: wordplay, steganography, english

1. They cost ≈  $0.00833333333333333333333333333333 each.
   `(9)    -_----_-_-----`
2. Go! Intentionally fracture your fibula!
   `(8)    -----_-_---`
3. You are the joints of the lower appendages of a eusocial animal.
   `(4)    --- --_---_--- -_-----`*
4. I bequeath unto you the frigid glenohumeral joint.
   `(10)   - -_------_---_---_----_--------`*
5. You and the curvy peg are now parting ways, thanks to me.
   `(13)   - -_-------_---_---_---_----`*
6. A conglomeration of wind, precipitation, humidity and temperature is above me as I randomly touch various things with my hands.
   `(11)   - -_-------_-----_---_-------`*
7. Prevent blood-sucking parasites from using their mandibles, and slumber securely.
   `(23)   -----_-----_---_--- -_---_---_---_----_----`*
8. Refrain from enumerating avian live stock prenatally.
   `(21)   --- -_-----_----_--------_------_---- --_-------`*
9. The pump which both delivers and retrieves molecules from every component of my construct has stopped its function.
   `(4)    --_-----_--_------`
10. Visible collections of gaseous vapors are plated without exception.
    `(2)    -----_-----_---_-_------_------`
11. Retrieve and refasten your various body parts at once!
    `(10)   ----_--------_--------`
12. While you are entertained, the fourth dimension is airborne.
    `(13)   ----_-----_----_---_---_------_---`

**ANSWER:**
`----__---__-----`

---

*Punctuation is indicated, but doesn t count.

*(A-la [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61639/my-first-is-in-the-kill-zone-but-not-in-no-mans-land), the answer is an unsolicited hint (and shameless plug) for [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66268/you-dont-need-any-hints).*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They cost ≈ $0.00833333333333333333333333333333 each.

> **A DIME A DOZEN** (9th letter = **Z**)

Go! Intentionally fracture your fibula!

> **BREAK A LEG!** (8th letter = **E**)

You are the joints of the lower appendages of a eusocial animal.

> **YOU'RE THE BEE'S KNEES** (4th letter = **R**)

I bequeath unto you the frigid glenohumeral joint.

> **I'M GIVING YOU THE COLD SHOULDER** (10th letter = **O**)

You and the curvy peg are now parting ways, thanks to me.

> **I'M LETTING YOU OFF THE HOOK** (13th letter = **O**)

A conglomeration of wind, precipitation, humidity and temperature is above me as I randomly touch various things with my hands.

> **I'M FEELING UNDER THE WEATHER** (11th letter = **N**)

Prevent blood-sucking parasites from using their mandibles, and slumber securely.

> **SLEEP TIGHT AND DON'T LET THE BED BUGS BITE** (23rd letter = **E**)

Refrain from enumerating avian live stock prenatally.

> **DON'T COUNT YOUR CHICKENS BEFORE THEY'VE HATCHED** (21st letter = **S**)

The pump which both delivers and retrieves molecules from every component of my construct has stopped its function.

> **MY HEART IS BROKEN** (4th letter = **E**)

Visible collections of gaseous vapors are plated without exception.

> **EVERY CLOUD HAS A SILVER LINING** (2nd letter = **V**)

Retrieve and refasten your various body parts at once!

> **PULL YOURSELF TOGETHER** (10th letter = **E**)

While you are entertained, the fourth dimension is airborne.

> **TIME FLIES WHEN YOU ARE HAVING FUN** (13th letter = **N**)

ANSWER: ----__---__-----

> **ZERO__ONE__SEVEN**

Comment: The first one is 1/120, not 1/12. So, how do you get dozen?

Comment: @Sid 1/120 = 1/12 of a dime (American coin which is worth 1/10 of a dollar)

Comment: *That* canine appears able to scour nearby fields and wooded areas in order to track and kill its prey, either for sport or for sustenance! Your ✅ is in the mail.