# According to String Theory

Tags: knowledge, steganography, music

In addition to being quite similar to [my previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66396/why-alexa-shouldnt-teach-non-native-english-speakers-about-idioms) in construct, this puzzle has the dubious honor of being another hint for [this hintless question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66268/you-dont-need-any-hints).

---

1. `Bm  F#  A  E  G  D  Em  F#`
   `(4) -----_----------`
2. `Am    C(G)    D(F#)    F    E`
   `(15) ----_- -_-----_-----_--- *`
3. `A7 D    A7 D    G A    G A    G    Bm`
   `(4) ----_-_------_---`
4. `Am C D F Am C E7     Am C D F Am E Am`
   `(15) -----_--_---_------_---`
5. `Am Dm(F#) Em G Am F Em G Am D G C Am    Bm D`
   `(7) -----_------`
6. `G D Em    F C D    G D Em    F C D    F C D`
   `(8) ----_----`
7. `G F# Bm    C D G F# C D G F# F D G Am Bm C G Am Bm C A7 G# G`
   `(7) ----_-----`

**ANSWER:**
`----__---`

---

As was terribly important in the last one:
***Punctuation is indicated, but doesn t count.**

Hints for unsolved, #2 and #5:

> #2-LZ #5-RH

Comment: Unfortunately, the xkcd [String Theory](https://xkcd.com/171/) has too short a title.

Comment: I'm really sad I don't have my guitar nearby. This seems like a fun puzzle.

Comment: @IanMacDonald [Here ya go!](https://www.jamplay.com/tools/guitar-chord-finder/)

Comment: Yeah, my phone also has a guitar on it... but it's not the same! :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> Hotel_California by The Eagles, letter 4 = e

2.

> Babe I'm gonna live you by Led Zeppelin, letter 15 = v

3.

> Give_a_little_bit by Supertramp, letter 4 = e

4.

> House_of_the_rising_sun by The Animals, letter 15 = n

5.

> Karma Police by Radiohead, letter 7 = o

6.

> Free_bird by Lynyrd Skynyrd, letter 8 = d

7.

> Sexy_sadie by The Beatles, letter 7 = d

**ANSWER:**

> even__odd

Special thanks to @IanMcDonald and @ManyPinkHats for solving the remaining two songs.

Comment: I thought that #7 would be the hard one. All answers correct so far!

Comment: @Chowzen I'm stuck on the last two. Any chance on getting a hint?

Comment: i feel the need to wait a while, give the rest of the world a crack at it, ya know?

Comment: Given the hints, #2 is ROT13(onor v'z tbaan yrnir lbh) and #5 is ROT13(xnezn cbyvpr)

Comment: That's it! Acceptance forthcoming...

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer.

2.

> Babe I'm gonna leave you - Led Zeppelin

Comment: Nice! Seeing your comment above, you must've gotten this without aural input. +1

Comment: It's a song I've played many times. (And is actually my "time to go home" alarm during my workday.)